# PHP foreach duplicates subarrays with identical content

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm using a multidimensional php array to supply data for html generation, and I've noticed some strange behavior when two of my subarrays (which have different keys) contain identical values. For example, this array produces duplicates:

```
$tableArray = Array(
    'rome' => Array(
        0 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'AWE',
            'home_number' => '122',
            'home_title' => 'Beginning Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to stuff'
        )
    ),
    'istanbul' => Array(
        0 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'RPED',
            'home_number' => '103',
            'home_title' => 'Beginning Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to Greek concepts of stretchiness'
        ),
        1 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'RPED',
            'home_number' => '104',
            'home_title' => 'Theory of Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to concepts of stretchiness'
        )
    ),
    'new york' => Array(
        0 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'RPED',
            'home_number' => '103',
            'home_title' => 'Beginning Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to Greek concepts of stretchiness'
        ),
        1 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'RPED',
            'home_number' => '104',
            'home_title' => 'Theory of Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to concepts of stretchiness'
        )
    )
);

foreach ($tableArray as $locationTab):
                echo '<p>' . array_search($locationTab, $tableArray) . '</p>';
endforeach;
```

Output:

rome

istanbul

istanbul

But when I add another subarray so the last two arrays aren't identical, there is no duplication:

```
$tableArray = Array(
    'rome' => Array(
        0 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'AWE',
            'home_number' => '122',
            'home_title' => 'Beginning Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to stuff'
        )
    ),
    'istanbul' => Array(
        0 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'RPED',
            'home_number' => '103',
            'home_title' => 'Beginning Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to Greek concepts of stretchiness'
        ),
        1 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'RPED',
            'home_number' => '104',
            'home_title' => 'Theory of Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to concepts of stretchiness'
        )
    ),
    'new york' => Array(
        0 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'RPED',
            'home_number' => '103',
            'home_title' => 'Beginning Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to Greek concepts of stretchiness'
        ),
        1 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'RPED',
            'home_number' => '104',
            'home_title' => 'Theory of Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to concepts of stretchiness'
        ),
        2 => Array(
            'home_prefix' => 'RPED',
            'home_number' => '104',
            'home_title' => 'Theory of Stretching',
            'abroad_prefix' => 'ARCH',
            'abroad_number' => '111',
            'abroad_title' => 'Intro to concepts of stretchiness'
        )
    )
);
```

Output:

rome

istanbul

new york

**How can I solve this problem so foreach doesn't duplicate the subarrays?** While my second-level keys will be unique, there may be situations where the values in two or more of my second-level arrays are identical.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I had forgotten to use the newly created `$key` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function `array_search` returns the first element in an array that matches the search pattern. that means if two elements have the same value, using `array_search` on the second element will always return the key of the first element

If you want the key use `foreach` like this :

```
foreach ($tableArray as $key => $locationTab) {
    echo '<p>' . $key . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the **first** corresponding key if successful

What you can do here is to remove that index after the output:

```
foreach ($tableArray as $locationTab) {
    $loc = array_search($locationTab, $tableArray);
    unset($tableArray[$loc]);
    echo '<p>' . $loc . '</p>';
}
```

I didn't understand exactly what you want with this code, but this is a solution. I guess there is a better way to do what you want.